# How do I distribute $n$ things among three people?

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking for the calculation of the following relationship.

I have 3 people and 3 apples. Now there are 10 ways to divide the three apples among the people.
$(1,1,1);(3,0,0);(0,3,0);(0,0,3);(2,1,0);(2,0,1);(1,2,0);(1,0,2);(0,2,1)$ and $(0,1,2)$.
Now how do I calculate the number if there are not only three apples, but n apples, but still for three people. Thanks for your help!

Comment: See [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: It is equivalent to $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ with $x_i\geq 0$. The number of solutions is ${n+2}\choose 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have the three apples, which we'll write as A, and you're going to insert two dividers, which we'll write as D, so that whatever is to the left of the first D goes to the first person, whatever is between the two D's goes to the second person, and whatever is to the right of the second D goes to the third person.

This is equivalent to your question (and corresponds to the Stars and Bars method mentioned in a comment) and can be counted by starting with five A's, and then considering how many ways you can transform two of the A's into D's.

For example, we could turn AAAAA into DAADA, which is what you called $(0,2,1)$.

More generally, we are choosing two of the five A's to turn into D's, which means we'll have $_5 C_2 = 10$ possible outcomes, which matches that which you found by hand.

For $n$ apples, you would have $n+2$ A's and count the number of ways to transform two of them into D's. The resulting total would, therefore, be:

$$_{n+2} C_2 = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}$$

Answer (score -1):

$$\dfrac{(n-1+3)!}{3!(n-1)!} $$
You can imagine the persons as barrers, then you use the permutation with repetition for $n-1$ barrers and $3$ apples.